# 1 error prohibited this channel from being saved:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a rails app with users and posts, i have added another sacffold called channels, now the relationship goes like the user can create both post and channels and the channels belongs to users, post belongs to both users and channels, to add user id to channels i have created a migration, everything looks good but i am getting this error while creating a channel.
[(Here is a screenshot of the exact error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqHcy.png)

**This is what am getting on the command line:**

```
Started POST "/channels" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-16 13:30:32 +0530
Processing by ChannelsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IJvvEe+TR6buacH5UwtiLSJglMkq7a+Q4x7VOTqALcGka4j6tG7lPi/7kYnCQ/nzmO7PNe2eSan3sBz9NqKV2g==", "channel"=>{"name"=>"dhfkdhfk", "description"=>"jdfjdfh", "tagline"=>"jdfjdfhj", "category"=>"jdfjdf", "avatar"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Channel"}
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (2.6ms)  BEGIN
   (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered channels/_form.html.erb (11.5ms)
  Rendered channels/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_avatar_dropdown.html.erb (7.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alert_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 367ms (Views: 345.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
```

**Add_user_id_to_channel.rb**

```
class AddUserIdToChannels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :channels, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**channel.rb**

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :description, :user_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :google_oauth2]

         act_as_mentionee

  validates :username, presence: true
  validate :avatar_image_size

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :channels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

  after_destroy :clear_notifications
  after_commit :send_welcome_email, on: [:create]


  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  include UserFollowing
  include TagFollowing
  include SearchableUser
  include OmniauthableUser


  private

    # Validates the size on an uploaded image.
    def avatar_image_size
      if avatar.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:avatar, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end

    # Returns a string of the objects class name downcased.
    def downcased_class_name(obj)
      obj.class.to_s.downcase
    end

    # Clears notifications where deleted user is the actor.
    def clear_notifications
      Notification.where(actor_id: self.id).destroy_all
    end

    def send_welcome_email
      WelcomeEmailJob.perform_later(self.id)
    end
end
```

**user_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def show
    @followers_count = @user.followers.count
    @following_count = @user.following.count
    @latest_posts = @user.posts.latest(3).published
    @recommended_posts = @user.liked_posts.latest(4).published.includes(:user)
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :edit, alert: "Could not update, Please try again"
    end
  end

  private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:description, :avatar, :location, :username)
    end

    def authorize_user
      unless current_user.slug == params[:id]
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
end
```

**channel_controller**

```
class ChannelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_channel, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /channels
  # GET /channels.json
  def index
    @channels = Channel.all
  end

  # GET /channels/1
  # GET /channels/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /channels/new
  def new
    @channel = Channel.new
    @channel = current_user.channels.build
    @user = current_user
  end

  # GET /channels/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /channels
  # POST /channels.json
  def create
    @channel = current_user.channels.build(channel_params)
    @channel = Channel.new(channel_params)
    @user = current_user


    respond_to do |format|
      if @channel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @channel, notice: 'Channel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @channel }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @channel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /channels/1
  # PATCH/PUT /channels/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @channel.update(channel_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @channel, notice: 'Channel was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @channel }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @channel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /channels/1
  # DELETE /channels/1.json
  def destroy
    @channel.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to channels_url, notice: 'Channel was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_channel
      @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def channel_params
      params.require(:channel).permit(:name, :description, :tagline, :category, :avatar, :user_id)
    end

    def authorize_user
      begin
        @channel = current_user.channels.find(params[:id])
      rescue
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model of channel you made it 'user_id' compulsory filed by adding presence: true

```
validates :name, :description, :user_id, presence: true
```

so you have to pass user_id in your parameters. you can do that by adding hidden_filed in your view as

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user %>
```

or if you don't required 'user_id' remove form validates like these:

```
validates :name, :description, presence: true
```

Comment: have you able to solve your issue with above solution?

Comment: no @lg86 i have already added :user_id in my the params of my channels model file you can check it in my question, does i have to add it somewhere else?

Comment: I mean you not pass user_id in below  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IJvvEe+TR6buacH5UwtiLSJglMkq7a+Q4x7VOTqALcGka4j6tG7lPi/7kYnCQ/nzmO7PNe2eSan3sBz9NqKV2g==", "channel"=>{"name"=>"dhfkdhfk", "description"=>"jdfjdfh", "tagline"=>"jdfjdfhj", "category"=>"jdfjdf", "avatar"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Channel"} and that is the reason you get user can't be balnk

Comment: but that's the command line result of the channel params and user_id is already there in channel params

Comment: In model of channel you made it 'user_id' compulsory filed by adding presence: true so you have to pass user_id in your parameters. you can do that by adding hidden_filed in your view as <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user %>

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@channel = current_user.channels.build(channel_params)
@channel = Channel.new(channel_params)
```

To

```
@channel = current_user.channels.build(channel_params)
```